# permission-denied when i log in or log out

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, flutter-getx

I check "is `user` logged in or logged out" with Getx.
I got permission-denied error when I log in or log out to my app with verify phone number. but I restart my App then It works without error when I got:

> Exception has occurred.
> FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)

here my phone authentication dart

```
class PhoneAuthController extends GetxController {

  static PhoneAuthController instance = Get.find();
  late Rx<User?> _user;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  CollectionReference subscribers = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("subscribers");
  
  @override
  void onReady(){
    super.onReady();
    _user = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser);
    _user.bindStream(auth.userChanges());
    ever(_user, _initialScreen);
  }

  _initialScreen(User? user){
    if(user==null){
      Get.offAll(()=> const VerifyByNumber());
    } else {
      String number = user.phoneNumber.toString().substring(1);
      var subscriber = subscribers.doc(number);
      subscriber.update({"userId": user.uid});
      Get.offAll(()=>HomePage(phoneNumber: number,));
    }
  }

  void verifyPhoneNumber(String uPhoneNumber) {
    String number = uPhoneNumber.substring(1);
      auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120),
          phoneNumber: uPhoneNumber,
          verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) {});
          },
          verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          },
          codeSent: (String id, int? token) {
            Get.off(() =>
                VerifyToCode(
                    phoneNumber: number,
                    verifyId: id,));
          },
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {});
  }

  void verifyCode(String uPhoneNumber, String verifyId, String smsCode) {
    Map<String, dynamic> subscriberToSave = {
      "phone": "+$uPhoneNumber",
      "name": null,
      "email": null,
      "password": null,
      "fcmToken": null,
      "date": DateTime.now()
    };
    try {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("subscribers").doc(uPhoneNumber).set(subscriberToSave);
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verifyId, smsCode: smsCode);
      auth.signInWithCredential(credential);   
      Get.offAll(VerificationSuccessfulScreen(number: uPhoneNumber));      
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("verifyCode, ERROR:", ">$e");
    }
  }

  void quitFirebaseAuth() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

here my firestore rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /subscribers/{subscriber} {
    
        allow get, write: if isSignIn() && 
        request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId && 
        request.auth.token.phone_number == resource.data.phone;
        
            match /sites/{site} {
            allow read, write: if isSignIn();
          match /messages/{message}{
            allow read, write: if isSignIn();
          }
        }
    }
    match /sites/{site} {
        allow read, write: if isSignIn();
    }
  } 
  
  function isSignIn(){
    return request.auth.uid != null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to write the user document does:

```
Map<String, dynamic> subscriberToSave = {
  "phone": "+$uPhoneNumber",
  "name": null,
  "email": null,
  "password": null,
  "fcmToken": null,
  "date": DateTime.now()
};
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("subscribers").doc(uPhoneNumber).set(subscriberToSave);
```

Your rules that allow/deny this write are:

```
match /subscribers/{subscriber} {    
    allow get, write: if isSignIn() && 
    request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId && 
    request.auth.token.phone_number == resource.data.phone;
```

You don't set a `userId` field anywhere in the code, so this check will fail `request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId` and the write will be rejected.

You should either add a `userId` field with the correct value to the data, or remove that check from your rules.

---

In general, you'll want to use `request.resource` rather than `resource` when validating data in write rules. The `resource` variable contains the resource as it exists **before** the operation, while `request.resource` is the resource as it'll exist after the operation (assuming the operation is allowed).